# Paste as Value when cell is empty (google-apps-script)

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently I am using the following script:

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange('Sheet1!C16:C16');
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Sheet2!A1'), {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear();
}
```

However I want to append the pasted data in sheet2 with new data that is generated weekly.

So once a week sheet1 is updated and the value in 'Sheet1!C16' will change. I want to append this in 'Sheet2!A2'. and so forth.

So how can I edit this script to make sure the new value is copied in the next empty cell (so when 'Sheet2!A1' has a value get the new value from 'Sheet1!C16' and copy it to 'Sheet2!A2'. And when 'Sheet2!A1'is has a value, copy the new value from 'Sheet1!C16' to 'Sheet2!A3'

I need to to this for all weeks of the year (so just to be safe 53 weeks)

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends, you can do a few things.

The first one is the easiest, however there is a condition. If each week you copy to cell `A1` → `A2` → `A3` and just keep going down, then each week, that data that you copy over is always the lowest. So for example if you wish to copy data to cell `A3` that means that the last row to have any data in any column is row `2`. That way all you need to do is get the range like this: `ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1)`

The other method is to use `PropertiesService` to store which row is the last one in use. On script run, get that value

```
var nextRow = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('property we added before')
```

and then when you get the target range you use

```
ss.getRange(nextRow, 1)
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('property we added before', nextRow + 1)
```

that way you get the next row each time and you update the property for the next time you wish to run. With this you also need to keep in mind that you might want to reset the counter after the year.